# Error de visualización campo fecha en Android e iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css

que onda muchachos tengo un problema con HTML, el tipo *date* en Android 12/13 sale en blanco, sin mostrarme el formato *dd/mm/aaaa* (me refiero a la caja no el popup de la fecha). Tampoco sale el ícono.

En iOS lo mismo. ¿hay alguna forma de arreglarlo?

Les paso el código de ejemplo, basicamente se ve blanco, sin placeholder; además en iOS el `<select>` y los *date* no se ven en relación con los *input* normales, se ven mas delgados.

He intentado todo lo que me ha dicho chatgpt foros y mas cosas pero nada, estoy usando flask, javascript, CSS y HTML. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```css
.form-input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 13px 22px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #dde3ec;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #536387;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}


.form-input:hover:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #787d9a;
}


.form-input::placeholder {
  color: rgba(83, 99, 135, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-space-down">
    <label for="start-date" class="form-label">Birthday?</label>
    <input 
      type="date" 
      name="birthday"
      id="birthday" 
      class="form-input"
      required
    />
  </div>
```